# Finding an orthonormal basis which diagonalizes a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given the linear operator $T: \Re^{3} \rightarrow \Re^{3}$ given by the formula $T(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{1}{25} (7x_1-24x_3, -25x_2, -24x_1-7x_3)$. The first part of the question asks us to deduce that $T$ is a self-adjoint isometry. I have done this by examining the matrix of $T$.

$M(T) =
\begin{matrix}
\frac{7}{25} & 0 & \frac{-24}{25} \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
\frac{-24}{25} & 0 & \frac{-7}{25} \\
\end {matrix} $

Clearly this is self-adjoint at $T=T^{*}$ and with simple calculations we can see that $\parallel Tv\parallel=\parallel v \parallel$.

The second part of the question asks to find an orthonormal basis of $\Re^{3}$ that diagonalizes T. From the real spectral theorem, we know that $\exists$ an orthonormal basis consisting of the eigenvectors of $T$ if and only if $T$ is self-adjoint. So could we simply find the eigenvalues of $T$ $(\lambda_1 = -1,\lambda_2 = -1, \lambda_3 = 1)$ and then say that their eigenvectors are the corresponding orthonormal basis that diagonalizes $M(T)$?

i.e $v_1=(\frac{3}{4}, 0,1), v_2=(0,1,0), v_3=(\frac{-4}{3}, 0, 1)$

However, there appears to be an error as $v_1$ and $v_3$ are not normalized.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're pretty much there, you just need to noramlize your vectors. Remember if $v$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector $A$, then so is $\mu v$ for all $\mu\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. So just choose a corresponding unit vector for each vector.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So normalizing them would still preserve the eigenbasis property of $v_1,v_2,$ and $v_3$ as you are simply dividing by the magnitude of each eigenvector, which is a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rescale your eigenvectors to be norm 1, ie $v_1/\lVert v_1\rVert = (3/5, 0, 4/5), v_3/\lVert v_3\rVert = (-4/5, 0, 3/5)$.

Comment: That's what I thought the appropriate step was, but by the real spectral theorem shouldn't $v_1, v_2,$ and $v_3$ already have been normalized?

Comment: I'm not sure how you calculated the $v_i$, but most methods require rescaling to norm 1 at some point.